# should I use integer or text on sqlite3

Tags: android, sqlite, boolean, database-performance

I'm a Android developer. I want to create a table on SQLite3, and I want a column for boolean type. I can define a column, type is integer, and the value only use 0 and 1. I also can use a column which type is text(char), and use value 'T', 'F'. which one smaller and faster?

Comment: "INTEGER. The value is a signed integer, stored in 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, or 8 bytes depending on the magnitude of the value." I guess using 1 byte to store a BOOL isn't too bad

Comment: Thanks very much. But if I use the text type, it will be stored as UTF-8 text, 'T' and 'F' is ascii character, also will use one byte, isn't it?

Comment: @DerGolem UTF-8 uses one byte per ASCII character. And as you can see in the [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/fileformat2.html#record_format), integers 0 and 1 use *zero* bytes (these values are handled with the serial types).

Comment: @DerGolem That's why I said "ASCII".

Comment: @CL Ah, OK. As usual, you have a deeper knowledge than mine.

Comment: Valuable information. Thanks everyone again!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use integer because that is suggested in official docs,

> SQLite does not have a separate Boolean storage class. Instead, Boolean values are stored as integers 0 (false) and 1 (true).

[See Docs](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html)